# Execute migrations in production but they are not created in my server

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

I try to create the migrations with the command but not copy the files

```
sudo docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: Why do you want to create the migrations on your server, the migrations are database-independent. In fact frequently migrations are edited by a user, so these are things that belong to a project, and should be checked in in your project.

Comment: Because the project has the migrations in the server and the repository had in the gitignore the migration files @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I doubt that it is done to me, it is because it does not create the files. In other occasions or in other unfolding they are created without any problem. Of equal I will take into account the migrations in local and upload them to the repo
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: You need to take the migrations out of the ignore files and commit them to the repo.

Comment: @DanielRoseman When I make the makemigrations in local and I want to make the migration in production I get "Your models have changes that are not reflected in a migration, and so will not be applied.
   Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them. ", For this reason I did not manage the migrations in my repositories, what can I do?

Comment: I faced the same issue. Is there any correct solution for this ?